# Slider con WP_Query en Wordpress no funciona bien

Tags: php, wordpress, slider

Tengo 2 sliders (.slide1 y .slide2) en el inicio de mi web.
Si es un móvil muestro .slide1 y oculto .slide2, y si no pues viceversa.
Ambos sliders funcionan pero quiero que muestren 3 fotos solo, y el problema es que muestran mas cosas a parte de esas fotos, hay momentos en los que se queda vacio sin mostrar nada, no lo entiendo.

Código del slide1 (el .slide2 es igual solo que ataca a otros 3 posts):

```
<div class="slide1">  
<?php
  $slider = new WP_Query(array(
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'posts_per_page' => 100,
      'post_status' => 'publish',        


  ));

  if($slider->have_posts()) :
  while($slider->have_posts()) : $slider->the_post(); 
  //if ( in_category( 3 )  : 
  if( (get_the_ID() == 76) OR (get_the_ID() == 78) OR (get_the_ID() == 80)) :
      echo "<br/>-->".get_the_ID();
?>

    <div class="w3-display-container mySlides mySlidesPortada">
        <a href="#"><?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?></a>
    </div>

  <?php 
  endif;
  endwhile;
  endif;
  ?>
</div>
```

Y el script:

```
<script>


var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
    setTimeout(carousel, 4000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
</script>
```

Comment: Acabo de comprobar que el problema está en el script, por algún momento el for cuenta 5 items y por tanto hay dos bucles que no llega a colocar el estilo "block" a los sliders y por eso no se ven.

Comment: El problema era el script, había conflicto ya que usaba un mismo script para los dos sliders, ya he creado otro para el segundo y funciona. Disculpad.. :)